# Clustering Many Coordinates and putting to Folium

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, folium

I have tried looking everywhere, and nothing seems to be working. I am trying to cluster 902,538 data points that include a latitude and longitude, but I can't seem to make it work! I have tried all sorts of clustering methods, and don't understand what is not working. Any tips?

dfnypd is a crime report that includes latitudes and longitudes for all reported crimes in New York in a given timeframe.

This is one of the codes I tried - giving me a ValueError: n_samples=2 should be >= n_clusters = 100

`dfnypd = dfnypd[['Latitude','Longitude']].apply(pd.to_numeric)`

`clat = dfnypd['Latitude']`

`clon = dfnypd['Longitude']`

`from sklearn.cluster import KMeans`

`X = np.array(([clat, clon]))`

`kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 100, random_state = 0).fit(X)`

I am clustering it into groups so that I can plot them on a readable chart and assign weights to the different clusters based upon crimes committed in those clusters. I tried just plotting it all as a heatmap, but it takes way too much power.

Answer (score 0):

Folium itself has a cluster plugin that can dynamically cluster your markers when you zoom in and out:

[folium's plugin MarkerCluster](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/MarkerCluster.ipynb)